# .NET Core Web API with Swagger: Post both a file AND data on the same call

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a .NET Core 3.1 Web API and I use swagger for the documentation/preview of it. I want to both upload a file and send a long some data to a post call. I can make 1 call to upload data and that works. I can make another call to send object data and that works. **But trying to combine the 2 together (by using swagger interface to fill out the data) never hits the method and gives me the error: Unsupported Media Type.**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Send")]
    public void Send(IFormFile file, Email emailInfo)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test")]
    public void Test(IFormFile file)
    {

    }

    public class Email
    {
        public List<string> To { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Files { get; set; }
    }
```

One thing you may notice is on the Send I have IFromFile as a parameter but IFromFile in Email obejct as well. For some reason in order for Swagger to show the file select button in the parameters it needed to be in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [From Query] binding:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Send")]
    public void Send([FromQuery] Email emailInfo)
    {
        var emailFromParam = emailInfo;
    }
```

Input:

[image: Swagger params]

Debug output showing param values:

[image: Debug window showing param values]